# I want the data i receive from API to be saved and passed to an URL in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, components

I want the data i receive from API to be saved and passed to an URL in Angular?

SERVICE.ts

```js
readonly rootUrl = 'http://localhost:49940/';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getUserName(): Observable<any> {
  return  this.http.get<any>(this.rootUrl+'api/Account/GetUserClaims');
}

get(userName: string): Observable<any> {
  let URL = `https://...?codSog=${userName}`;
  return this.http.get<any>(URL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your fetch the data from the api:

```
get(item: T): Observable<T> {
  return this.http.get<T>('apiUrl');
}
```

save it :

```
save(){
  this.get().subscribe(res => this.savedItem = res,
    err => console.log(err),
    _ => console.log('item saved'));
}
```

send it to the next url:

```
send(item: T): Observable<T> {
  return this.http.post<T>('destinationUrl', item):
}
```